# How to get distinct values from many columns of table using sqlAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a database with these tables in it

```
Employee(id, name, deptid, salary)
Department(id, name)
```

with these values in it

```
Employee
id     | name       | deptid     | salary.   |
------- ------------ ------------ -----------
1        Alex           1            600000
2        Larry          1            700000
3        Jesse          3            400000
4        Alex           2            500000
5        Marcus         3            400000

Department
id      | name      |
-------- ----------- 
1.       Engineering
2.       Finance
3.       Sales
```

I want to fetch the distinct values from every column of the database
I want the output to look something like this

```
name    
------
Alex
Larry
Jesse
Marcus

deptid
-------
1
3
2
```

I have written a ORM query like this

```
session.query(Employee.name, Employee.deptid).distinct().all()
```

this returns me

```
[('Alex',1,), ('Larry',1), ('Jesse', 3),('Alex',2),('Marcus',3)]
```

this is returning distinct values of both columns combined, which is not the desired solution I am looking for rather I am looking for rather I want the solution with distinct values of different columns in one query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` is applied to the full rows that are being selected.

You will therefore need two `SELECT DISTINCT` queries to find the distinct values in two different columns.

```py
session.query(Employee.name).distinct().all()

session.query(Employee.deptid).distinct().all()
```

You should also use `Department.id` directly to find its distinct values, rather than using the foreign key `Employee.deptid`, unless you only want to find the referenced ones.